# implications of compiling Google Protocol Buffers without stl debugging info

Tags: c++, stl, protocol-buffers

I have some file. Let's call it *Msg.proto*

I use Google's Protocol Buffer protoc.exe compiler to take my proto file and it generates a *Msg.h* file, which contains the definition for a *Msg* class.

When I delete a *Msg* object it can take a really long to deallocate the memory (when the debugger is attached). This is because it is using the STL debug library. So, I want to disable STL debugging when I delete *Msg* objects, but I want to keep STL debugging for the rest of my project. This leads me to consider turning off STL debugging info for *Msg.h* and for the Google Protocol Buffer project (because this is used by the *Msg* class, and only by the *Msg* class).

What are the implications of this?

What I'm guessing is:

1. no STL objects created with STL debugging info can be passed into any of *Msg*'s functions/constructors/etc, because that would mean that an STL object created w/ one version if the STL library is then being passed to a portion of the code that uses a different version of the STL library
2. others?

Comment: If you disable debugging for only one class as described you will likely end up violating the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: Right. You can *guarantee* it's gonna get hosed.

Comment: I was told that I can use Visual Studio to set preprocessor definitions for single files, thus disabling debugging for these files. You're saying that this should never be done?

Comment: I believe it can be done, if one is careful. That is what I am considering, but I wanted to know what the implications are.